# Problem with HPLIP 3.14.10 install

Tags: printing, hplip

I borked my install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and had to reinstall the OS. I didn't tinker with my /home partition, just reinstalled the OS to the /root partition.

When I download and install HPLIP 3.14.10 from the HP website, no matter how many times I run the setup GUI, I end up with the same error. To retrace my steps,

- I select Network/Ethernet/Wireless/ option and click Next.
- My device (HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M177fw) is recognized and I press the Next button
- I select Download and Install ... and press Next
- Error Message:   /home/****/.hplip/hplip-3.14.10-plugin.run file does not match its checksum.File may have been corrupted or altered

Used sudo to copy the relevant .ppd files (printer and fax) from my 14.04 LTS laptop to /etc/cups/ppd but the setup won't recognize .ppd files, only .run files.

Does any one have any ideas of what I can do? Is there a way to download the appropriate .run file(s) outside setup? BTW, I have no "checksum" data in the ~./hplip folder ... so I don't know what setup is using as the compare.

Please help. I'm desperate because this is my work computer and I need to be able to print and scan to earn a living.

Thanks, mojohn

P.S. I downloaded the plugin and checksum from www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/auxfiles/HP/plugins/ and ran a compare. The following error was reported: 
gpg: can't open `hplip-3.14.10.run.asc'
gpg: verify signatures failed: file open error

Got the same error when I ran a compare on 3.14.6 and 3.14.1. Appears there is something amiss at the website.

Maybe that helps??

Comment: Welcome to ask Ubuntu. Please do not put FIXED/SOLVED etc in the subject header of your question. You can answer your own question below where it says **Your Answer**. then you can accept your own answer by putting a green check mark next to it to mark it as "fixed."

Comment: @mojohn: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 1):

Answer from OP:

I copied the 3.14.10 plugin to `~/.hplip` and ran setup again. Setup complained that it couldn't verify the checksum, but asked if I wanted to install the file anyway. I clicked yes, and the install finished.